# sort by rows number where columns value are the same

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, count

I have this two tables :

categorie :

[image]

and another table named "thynk" :

[image]

each line in table thynk is linked with a categorie.

Anyway i would like to know if it's possible to select categorie_id which contains most of thynk ? (with postgresql)

So here i should have this result :

```
 categorie_id
--------------
           0
           5
           3
```

Comment: Yes it is possible, with Count, Group and Having, see here: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-having/

Comment: Have you yet learned to `COUNT` in SQL? And have you learned how to get aggregates by groups (e.g. by Category)?

Comment: no I just discovered group by :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group by `categoire_id`, count the results in each group and order accordingly:

```
SELECT   categorie_id, COUNT(*)
FROM     thynk
GROUP BY categorie_id
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: The `COUNT(*)` isn't strictly necessary in the `SELECT` statement, to answer the OP.  Just have `SELECT categorie_id FROM thynk GROUP BY categorie_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC`

Comment: Well and if i want order by a value with my count and limit by number 
not to select all columns, can i passed arguments at count ?

Comment: @Fantasim: What do you mean? I don't understand what you are asking (and I doubt someone else will).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Ahah sorry for my english.. So with "Select categorie_id from thynk group by categorie_id order by count( * ) desc;" i get categories which contains most thynk. But count( * ) make this rank by all thynks but if i need to make this rank by 50 last thynks? you see what i mean ? :/

Comment: @Fantasim: Rather than selecting from the table thynk directly, you'd select from a subquery on thynk containing `ORDER BY create_at DESC FETCH FIRST 50 ROWS ONLY` (or `LIMIT 50` for that matter).